# How do I make 'POST' work with Service Worker using Workbox?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm finding out ways of making POST requests work with Service Workers. I've decided to not cache the `.js` files; and did not include any code to handle `.js` files in my service worker. Here's ym SW for reference -

```
importScripts("/ce-sw-base-files/precache-manifest.99e329b365f3e07d00d5df746d12a847.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

// Google Analytics
workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize({
    parameterOverrides: {
        cd1: 'offline',
    },
});

// Install the service worker; and cache the layout files
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('ce-super-cache')
            .then(cache => {
                cache.addAll([
                    '/dashboard',
                    '/offline',
                    '/manifest.json'
                ]);
            })
    );
});

// Images Cache
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'images-cache',
        plugins: [
            new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                maxEntries: 20,
                maxAgeSeconds: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 5 Days
            }),
        ],
    }),
);

// Static Resources (Only CSS)
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:css)$/,
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'static-css-resources',
        plugins: [
            new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                maxEntries: 20,
                maxAgeSeconds: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 5 Days
            }),
        ],
    })
);

// Default strategy if not above.
workbox.routing.setDefaultHandler(
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly()
);

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        }).catch(() => {
            return caches.match('/offline');
        })
    )
});

workbox.routing.setCatchHandler(({event}) => {
    switch (event.request.destination) {
        case 'document':
            return caches.match('offline');
            break;

        // case 'image':
        //     return caches.match(FALLBACK_IMAGE_URL);
        //     break;
        //
        // case 'font':
        //     return caches.match(FALLBACK_FONT_URL);
        //     break;

        default:
            // If we don't have a fallback, just return an error response.
            return Response.error();
    }
});
```

In order to skip service worker from dealing with `.js` files, I've decided to not match any `.js` files. I've also tried using `NetworkOnly` as default strategy for all unmatched requests; but this doesn't work reliably.

I'm wondering if there's any way to totally skip `.js` files being catched / intercepted by the service worker so that I make regular POST requests?

At this point, I'm not able to convert to `fetch`; and have to rely on `axios` for my POST requests.

Would appreciate a solution/guidance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have worked on post recently. Can you please rephrase your question? I am not able to understand much right now.

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to configure serviceworker to ignore XHR POST requests? Currently serviceworker intercepts them and returns an error.